# Solve the integration $\int_{-2}^{2} \bigg(x^3 \cos(\frac{x}{2})+\frac{1}{2} \bigg)(\sqrt{4-x^2}) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve the integration $$\int_{-2}^{2} \bigg(x^3 \cos(\frac{x}{2})+\frac{1}{2} \bigg)(\sqrt{4-x^2}) dx$$ I tried so much but failed, but one thing I noticed that the interand is an even function. But it does not help me.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The first part of the integrand is odd. It will be zero. The second part is even. You can integrate it easily by subtitution method.

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: Answer should be $\pi$ based on what @Asit suggested.

Comment: Yes, @AliShather, $\pi$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, verify that

$$x^3 \text{ is an odd function}$$ 
$$\cos(\frac{x}{2})\text{ is an even function}$$
$$\sqrt{4-x^2}\text{ is an even function}$$

We have that the product of two even functions is an even function. But, the product of an even function and an odd function is an odd function. Therefore

$$x^3 \cos(\frac{x}{2})(\sqrt{4-x^2})$$

is an odd function. This allows us to simplify the integral to

$$\int_{-2}^{2} \bigg(x^3 \cos(\frac{x}{2})+\frac{1}{2} \bigg)(\sqrt{4-x^2}) dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} dx$$

In order to solve the integral on the RHS, we could use various different methods. I will show two different methods.

Method 1: We can draw the graph of $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ on the interval of $[-2,2]$. Remember that

$$x^2+y^2=4$$

is the equation of a circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin. Therefore

$$y^2=4-x^2$$

and

$$y=\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

so that $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is the semicircle above the $x$-axis. We could draw this semicircle by hand or by plotting it on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/). A plot on Desmos shows that

[image]

It is clear that the area of the entire circle is

$$A=\pi r^2=4\pi$$

We need to compute half of this area (as the semicircle has half of the area of the entire circle) which brings to total down to $2\pi$. We can then directly compute

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\pi\right)=\pi$$

Method 2: Instead of drawing the semicircle, we could apply integration by parts. Let

$$u=\sqrt{4-x^2}, ~du=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$
$$dv=dx, ~v=x$$

Then

\begin{align}\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} dx&=\Big[x\sqrt{4-x^2}\Big]_{-2}^2+\int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx\\&= 0 + \int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx \\&=
-\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{(4-x^2)-4}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx \\&=
-\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}dx + 4\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx
\end{align}

which means that

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} dx = 2\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx $$

and we know that

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx =\arcsin(x)+C$$

thus

\begin{align}\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} dx &= 2\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx \\&=2\Big(\arcsin(\frac{2}{2})-\arcsin(\frac{-2}{2})\Big)\\&= 2\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2})\\&=2\pi
\end{align}

so that

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\pi\right)=\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral into two parts $$\int_{-2}^2\bigg(x^3\cos{\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg(\sqrt{4-x^2}\bigg)dx=\int_{-2}^2 \bigg(x^3\cos{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg)\bigg(\sqrt{4-x^2}\bigg)dx+\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}dx.$$ First integrand is odd, second integrand is even. What can you conclude?

**Hint:** To evaluate the second integral you can make a trignometric substitution, or you can just recognize that the integrand is the equation of some part of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

See this video from MindYourDecision: https://youtu.be/Q1575oHNYRo. The answer is simply $\pi$.